# TinyMCE image resize handles are misaligned inside scaled containers

Tags: tinymce, scale, contenteditable, image-resizing, tinymce-4

**EDIT 2**: An even better solution, for me, was to just use offsetWidth and offsetHeight as that will return the width without the transformation applied. But `getBoundingClientRect()` was used for a reason, as there is a comment next to that part mentioning a bug with Gecko and resizing tables with captions. The application I am working on is quite cutting edge, and is only required to work on Google Chrome as it is an internal application, so this fix is better for me, but still not ideal.

---

**EDIT 1**: I have found a way to fix this, but it required changing the TinyMCE source code, since the application I'm working on keeps track of the scaling applied to the `contenteditable` area, I was able to just insert my scaling multiplier as a divisor and apply it to the `targetWidth` and `targetHeight` variables in the function `showResizeRect()` on lines 14,197 and 14,198 of the unminified tinymce.js file (as of v4.2.6).

This is not an ideal fix, so I preferably like to do this a better way, so if anybody knows of a better way that does not including changing the TinyMCE source, then please enlighten me.

You can see the bug report I filed [here](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=7711).

---

I'm having an issue with TinyMCE, I am working on a web application, and we are using an inline TinyMCE instance to edit content that is inside a scaled contenteditable container. However, when going to resize an image, the resize handles are smaller than the image. Here is a demonstrative image:

[image]

I have searched on Google, but did not find anything relevant. Is there a plugin, or perhaps a workaround that deals with this already?

Thanks in advance.